# cin and getline in one program, and only one of them takes effect?

Tags: c++, io

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char s1[23];
    char s2[23];
    // cin >> s1;
    cin.getline(s2, 22);
    cout << s1 << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment the line `cin >> s1`, then the getline function will be skipped, don't know why this happens.

Comment: Its working for me if uncommented.....

Comment: It is not skipped, however it has nothing more to read before the first newline.

Comment: You need to understand how `cin >>` and `cin.getline` handle line endings. With it un-commented, there is a line ending that is all the `getline` picks up.

Comment: [Take your pick.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not skipped, but you must understand how each input method treats whitespace. `>>` skips whitespace at start, then extracts until the next character is whitespace, and then stops. Note that it leaves that whitespace character in the stream.

`getline()` extracts until it extracts a newline (and discards the newline, not storing it).

So when `>>` runs, it reads the string. I assume you type a single word and `Enter` (which produces a newline). The word is extracted by `>>`, then it stops when it encounters the newline. **The newline remains in the stream.**

Then `getline()` runs and extracts characters until it extracts a newline. Guess what, that's the first character it finds - the one left behind by `>>`.